# CPLEX: freeing model (resources) takes immense time

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving a MIP and have built a corresponding CPLEX IloModel. My implementation follows the following pseudo-code:

```
model = IloModel( env );

//Build optimization model

//Configure CPLEX Solver

//Solve model

//Do some solution-statistics

model.end();
```

Everything works fine, I get correct solutions, et cetera. Now, I would like to automate solving a lot of different instances sequentially.

However, here I ran into a problem: the bigger my instances, the longer freeing resources using `model.end()` takes time. For my small instances (using up to 500mb of RAM) it already takes dozens of minutes, for medium sized instance (using up to 2 GB of RAM) it takes hours and I never measured how long it takes my large instances (using up to 32 GB of RAM), as I always manually killed the process after it did not finish over a whole nights wait. Therefore, freeing ressources takes significantly longer than building the model or solving it using my specified time-limits. While `model.end()` runs, the CPU usage always stays at roughly 100%.

Is this expected behaviour? Have I missed something in implementing my model or how to free resources that it takes this excessive amount of time?

I really want to avoid automating solving multiple instances in sequence through killing the CPLEX solve process after a specified time threshold.

Thank you!

EDIT:
I can circumvent the problem by running `env.end()` (which takes <1s even for large models) instead of `model.end()`. As I do not reuse the environment for now, that is ok for me. However, I wonder what is happening here, from what I gathered from the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloEnv.html#method_end), freeing the resources allocated for the model is a subprocess of freeing the whole environment.

Comment: Watch carefully how many nonzero elements you are generating. In large scale models, this is an important measure to keep in check (even at the expense of more variables/equations).

Comment: Thank you for that tip! So you say, it often happens that large scale models can be more performant than others, if they have less non-zeros even though they maybe have more variables/constraints?

Comment: Yes. I often see models with a large number of nonzero elements that thus require a ton of memory. I always look for ways to make the problem sparser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, but did you terminate the solver before terminating the model? The solver is using the model and so it is notified about its changes. It could be that `model.end()` is not optimized and as it is freeing constraints one by one, solver is notified about each particular change, it updates its own data structures etc.

In other words, I think that calling `cplex.end()` before `model.end()` may solve the issue.

If you can then it is always best to call `env.end()` after each solve. As you noticed, it is faster: it is easier to free all the resources at once since there's no need to check whether a particular resource is still needed (e.g. a variable could be used by multiple models). It is also safer since new model starts from scratch and the risk of a memory leak is minimized.

Comment: Your assumptions were correct, I did not end ```cplex``` before calling ```model.end()```, as I was not aware of this notification process. I did not test it, but I think from this point of view, it should also be possible to call  ```cplex.clearModel()``` to unextract the model from ```cplex```.